# Forgot Apache OFBIZ admin password

Tags: apache, tomcat, passwords, ofbiz

I've forgotten my password for the apache of biz admin account , I've asked for an email to be sent however I don't know which account is associated with the ofbiz server so I can't view the email which changed the password , does anyone have any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you can access database, you can make the change directly on the UserLogin table.

Otherwise if you have a remote access to the server, you can use the ant or gradle target - depending of your OFBiz revision - to create another admin acount :

```
gradlew loadAdminUserLogin -PuserLoginId=myadmin
```

or

```
ant create-admin-user-login
```

Answer (score 1):

Also a possible solution in such case is to use the (eg) [lmtadmin](https://demo-trunk.ofbiz.apache.org/partymgr/control/viewprofile?partyId=ltdadmin) if you have access to it. This is what I do on the demo when someone screws the main admin pwd